# Execute Shell Script using Http path in java program

Tags: java, shell, exec

i have a path where i have shell script which i have to execute using java program but i am getting error as .

```
Runtime.java

public class Runtime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Triggered");

        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"http://192.168.1.7/sh_scripts/check_process/2.sh\"");
            System.out.println(p);

                    } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}


LOGCAT

http://192.168.1.7/sh_scripts/check_process/2.sh: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at com.howtodoinjava.demo.poi.Runtiime.main(Runtiime.java:15)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

Did i miss anything while executing . The path is not geeting read from the java program to execute the shell script So please help me to execute the jar file using the given http link where i can execute the 2.sh file successfully using java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can only execute an executable FILE on the same computer, there is no support for downloading a script from a remote server in http, ftp or whatever else.

Same is true also in a normal unix shell.

So, you have a few options :

1. Download the .sh file yourself in java, put it in a temporary file, and execute it there
2. Run another .sh file that downloads the .sh file from http and executes it; can be a oneliner, like `source <(curl -s http://192.168.1.7/sh_scripts/check_process/2.sh)`
3. Try to execute this oneliner, maybe using ProcessBuilder can ease the creation of the redirection etc.. but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you friend it is very helpful for me to know . But one sincere request after this request can u put some sample program such that it will help me and others @Simone Gianni

Comment: Let the explanation be as it is like this as it is very useful. After that u give some code snippet @Simone Gianni Many thanks for your time and help Gracious words Simonne